# Navigating/moving through drop down list using arrow keys and picking the value by pressing enter

Tags: javascript

When entering text in text field it offers similar values by showing them in dropdown list.
How could I move through it using arrow keys? And pick some value by pressing enter button?
Any hints for improving my code?

```js
(function() {
  "use strict";

  let inputField = document.getElementById('input');
  let ulField = document.getElementById('suggestions');
  inputField.addEventListener('input', changeAutoComplete);
  ulField.addEventListener('click', selectItem);

  function changeAutoComplete({
    target
  }) {
    let data = target.value;
    ulField.innerHTML = ``;
    if (data.length) {
      let autoCompleteValues = autoComplete(data);
      autoCompleteValues.forEach(value => {
        addItem(value);
      });
    }
  }

  function autoComplete(inputValue) {
    let destination = [
      "A, 1",
      "B, 2",
      "C, 3",
      "D, 4",
      "E, 5",
      "F, 6",
      "A, 7",
      "B, 8",
      "C, 9",
      "D, 10"
    ];

    return destination.filter(
      (value) => value.toLowerCase().includes(inputValue.toLowerCase())
    );
  }

  function addItem(value) {
    ulField.innerHTML = ulField.innerHTML + `<li>${value}</li>`;
  }

  function selectItem({
    target
  }) {
    if (target.tagName === 'LI') {
      inputField.value = target.textContent;
      ulField.innerHTML = ``;
    }
  }
})();
```

```html
<input id="input" autocomplete>

<ul id="suggestions"></ul>
```